# How to write this list comprehension correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to code a list comprehension that sorts out dictionaries that are not duplicate. The data I'm working with looks like this:

```
[
    {
        'username': 'food_lovers_mad',
        'data': (some unique data)
    },
    {
        'username': 'oceanarmor',
        'data': (some unique data)
    },
    {
        'username': 'freediverlife',
        'data': (some unique data)
    }
]
```

And I'm sorting out the dictionaries with identical username and add them to a new list. This is my current approach:

```py
duplicates = [dup for outer in array for dup in
              [inner for inner in array
               if outer['username'] == inner['username']]]
```

EDIT: An example of input could be:

```
[
    {
        'username': 'duplicate',
        'data': {
            "watches": 1241,
            "followers": 71234
        }
    },
    {
        'username': 'duplicate',
        'data': {
            "watches": 12431,
            "followers": 151
        }
    },
    {
        'username': 'not duplicate',
        'data': {
            "watches": 2124,
            "followers": 54124
        }
    }
]
```

Which would produce the output:

```
[
    {
        'username': 'duplicate',
        'data': {
            "watches": 1241,
            "followers": 71234
        }
    },
    {
        'username': 'not duplicate',
        'data': {
            "watches": 2124,
            "followers": 54124
        }
    }
]
```

I'm really confused because I'm a bit new to list comprehension in python so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Sets automatically remove duplicate items.  `uniques = list(set(original_list))`

Comment: can you give an example case for duplicates & the expected output for the same?

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: Look at `itertools.groupby`. Your current approach takes O(n**2) time; sorting and grouping would only take O(n lg n) time.

Comment: I think what you are trying to write, though, is `[[inner for inner in array if inner['username'] == outer['username']] for outer in array]`.

Comment: @JohnGordon the data provided in each dict is unique, so this won't work right?

Comment: @kostberg can you provide a real example of inputs and outputs, your example is ambiguous to me... which `(some unique data)` would be kept??? Almost certainly, you don't want to use a list comprehension here.

Comment: @chepner or use the `dict` based grouping idiom for O(N) time.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is the update understandable now?

Comment: So you want to keep the *first* seen duplicate?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes

Comment: @kostberg use a for-loop and a set. That will be the most efficient way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a set to identify the duplicates:

```
seen = set()
duplicates = [d for d in array if d["username"] in seen or seen.add(d["username"])]
```

Comment: `in seen or seen.add(d["username"])` don't use side-effects and cutsey tricks in list comprehensions.